# How to Order a multidimensional List using another list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Quick Summary:

```
need_to_reorder = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

I want to set an order for the **need_to_reorder[0][x]** ***x*** values using my sorting array

```
sorting_array = [1, 3, 0, 2]
```

Required result: **need_to_reorder** will equal

```
[['b', 'd', 'a', 'c'], [2, 4, 1, 3]]
```

Searching for the answer, I tried using **numPy**:

```
import numpy as np
sorting_array = [1, 3, 0, 2]
i = np.array(sorting_array)
print i  ## Results: [1 3 0 2] <-- No Commas?
need_to_reorder[:,i]
```

RESULTS:

```
TypeError: list indicies must be integers, not tuple
```

I'm looking for a correction to the code above or an entirely different approach.

Comment: For input there is a csv file which is being read into a multidimensional array. Also, on input the client will give me instructions on how to reorder the data. There are some cleanup changes being made to some of the data. After the cleanup,  I want to reorder the data and print the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a simple nested comprehension

```
>>> l = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> s = [1, 3, 0, 2]
>>> [[j[i] for i in s] for j in l]
[['b', 'd', 'a', 'c'], [2, 4, 1, 3]]
```

If you need this as a function you can have a very simple function as in

```
def reorder(need_to_reorder,sorting_array)
    return [[j[i] for i in sorting_array] for j in need_to_reorder]
```

---

Do note that this can be solved using `map` function also. However in this case, a list comp is preferred as the `map` variant would require a `lambda` function. The difference between `map` and a list-comp is discussed in full length in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1247486/4099593)

Comment: yes, same as mine, but i think a dedicated function is more clear for something like this

Comment: @Pete ... `map` is a bit tedious here. I will add a few points as to why I chose a lisco over `map`. Dedicated funcs can be left to the OP. This is because he needs this as a plug-in. So we may as well wait for the OP to clarify

Comment: I think in terms of maps and lambdas. I guess not everyone else does (sigh)

Comment: @Pete Do avoid a `lambda` whenever possible.

Comment: @BhargavRao You forgot to put a function name.

Answer (score 0):

```
def order_with_sort_array(arr, sort_arr):
    assert len(arr) == len(sort_arr)
    return [arr[i] for i in sort_arr]

sorting_array = [1, 3, 0, 2]
need_to_reorder = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

after_reordered =  map(lambda arr : order_with_sort_array(arr, sorting_array), 
                      need_to_reorder)
```

Comment: I would have upvoted this answer if it wasn't a code block. It is a good answer, no doubt, but it needs some statements around it to.

Comment: I would but don't have enough karma or whatever to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```py
import numpy as np
ntr = np.array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
sa = np.array([1, 3, 0, 2])
print np.array( [ntr[0,] , np.array([ntr[1,][sa[i]] for i in range(sa.shape[0])])] )
>> [['a' 'b' 'c' 'd'],['2' '4' '1' '3']]
```